# Node.js and Express not working?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am currently trying to learn implementing RESTful APIs using Node.js & Express. Using this tutorial: http://code.runnable.com/U7bnCsACcG8MGzEc/restful-api-with-node-js-express-4

I created each file on my local drive and tried running the code using node server.js..However I kept on getting an error. Why might be causing this?

[image]

Comment: There is not a root router for / request in that code, you need to set one in the server.js.

Comment: Relevant code MUST be present in your question, not only available via an external link.  This is a Stack Overflow requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The code you chose to run is only routing requests for urls that begin with `/api` as you can see here:

```
app.use('/api', router);
```

On top of that, the routes it accepts are `/players` and `/player/:id`:

```
router.get('/players', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json({ players: players.getAllPlayer() });
});

router.get('/players/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  var player = players.getPlayerById(req.params.id)
  res.json(player);
});
```

For every request, including the routes above, it outputs the method and url to `console.log`.

Even when it fails to get `/`, you should see `GET /` in your console.

Now try to access this url: `0.0.0.0:8080/api/players`

It works, right?